# An inequality involving real numbers.......

Tags: real-analysis, inequality, cauchy-schwarz-inequality

> Given real numbers $a_1,a_2, \ldots , a_n$, let $S_1 = \sum_{i=1}^na_i$ and $S_2 = \sum_{i=1}^na_i^2$. Prove that
> $$S_1\sqrt{nS_2}\le S_1^2+\frac 12 \left \lfloor \frac{n^2}4 \right \rfloor \left(\max_i a_i - \min_i a_i \right)^2$$

I tried to use Cauchy Schwarz inequality. Any idea/hint will be appreciated.

Comment: Please explain how you used the inequality....

Comment: Hint: Fix $S_1$ and show that $S_2$ is maximized when all except possibly 1 of the $a_i$ term is equal to the min or max.

Answer (score 1):

very nice problem. I wish there would be a better solution than this. Throughout the solution, denote $M=\max_{1 \leq i \leq n}a_i$, and $m=\min_{1 \leq i \leq n}a_i$.

**Step 1**

$$nS_2 - S_1^2 \leq \frac{n^2}{4}(M-m)^2$$

***Proof of Step 1***

Note that the following holds.

$$n(a_i-M)(a_i-m) \leq 0, \quad \forall i=1,2, \cdots, n$$

By summing up these, we get the following.

$$nS_2 - S_1^2 \leq -n^2Mm+n(m+M)S_1-S_1^2 $$
$$= (S_1-nm)(nM-S_1) \leq \frac{n^2}{4}(M-m)^2 $$

The last inequality is just an AM-GM inequality.

**Step 2**

$$nS_2 - S_1^2 \leq \left \lfloor \frac{n^2} {4} \right \rfloor (M-m)^2$$

***Proof of Step 2***

It suffices to prove when $n \geq 2$ is odd, or $n=2k+1$ for some $k \in \mathbb{N}$.
WLOG $(a_i)_{i=1}^{2k+1}$ is an increasing sequence. Define $T_1$ and $T_2$ as below.

$$T_1 = \sum_{i=1}^{k} a_i +  \sum_{i=k+2}^{2k+1} a_i, \quad T_2 = \sum_{i=1}^{k} a_i^2 +  \sum_{i=k+2}^{2k+1} a_i^2 $$

By simple calculation, we get the following.

$$nS_2 - S_1^2 = nT_2- T_1^2 + \sum_{i=1}^{k}(a_{k+1}-a_i)^2 + \sum_{i=k+2}^{2k+1}(a_{k+1}-a_i)^2 $$

By **Step 1**, the following holds.

$$nT_2- T_1^2 \leq k^2(M-m)^2 $$

Also, note the following holds by the monotonicity.

$$\sum_{i=1}^{k}(a_{k+1}-a_i)^2 + \sum_{i=k+2}^{2k+1}(a_{k+1}-a_i)^2 = \sum_{i=1}^{k}\{ (a_{k+1}-a_i)^2 + (a_{2k+2-i}-a_{k+1})^2 \}$$

$$\leq \sum_{i=1}^{k} (a_{2k+2-i}-a_i)^2 \leq k(M-m)^2$$

By summing these two, we get the following.

$$nS_2-S_1^2 \leq (k^2+k)(M-m)^2 = \left \lfloor \frac{n^2} {4} \right \rfloor (M-m)^2$$

**Step 3**

$$S_1 \sqrt{nS_2} - S_1^2 \leq \frac{1}{2} \left \lfloor \frac{n^2} {4} \right \rfloor (M-m)^2$$

***Proof of Step 3***

Note that by C-S inequality, $\sqrt{nS_2}  \geq |S_1|$. Therefore, the following holds by **Step 2**.

$$S_1 \sqrt{nS_2} - S_1^2 \leq |S_1| \sqrt{nS_2} - S_1^2 = \frac{|S_1|}{|S_1|+ \sqrt{nS_2}} (nS_2 - S_1^2)$$

$$ \leq \frac{1}{2} (nS_2 - S_1^2) \leq \frac{1}{2} \left \lfloor \frac{n^2} {4} \right \rfloor (M-m)^2 $$

Equality holds if and only if $m=M \geq 0$.

Comment: Oh, I just fixed it. Thank you for your comment!

Comment: Also, you can use ```\left \lfloor \frac {n^2}{4} \right \rfloor ``` so that it renders as : $\left \lfloor \frac {n^2}{4} \right \rfloor$

Comment: Oh, thank you for your nice tip :)